# Splitting query into different views or tables using PostgreSQL/PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, attribute-joins

I'm working with PostgreSQL 14.1 with PostGIS 3.1. I've got two tables:

1. `grid` that holds a 10x10 km UTM grid, using field `utm` as PK.
2. `species` that holds fields `name` (for the species name), `utm` as a FK, and `status` (with the status of the species in that particular utm cell).

I've built the following query:

```
SELECT
 s.name, s.status, g.utm, g.geom
 FROM 
 species s
 JOIN grid g
 ON g.utm = s.utm;
```

But I need separate tables or views for each species. How could it be achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use procedural language PL/pgsql(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql.html), and loop over all your species.

Use `format()` function (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) to dynamically define table name.

You can start by :

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE r record;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN  SELECT DISTINCT name FROM species
    LOOP
        RAISE INFO 'Create table for %', r.name;
        EXECUTE FORMAT ('CREATE TABLE %I AS (SELECT  s.name, s.status, g.utm, g.geom FROM species s JOIN grid g ON g.utm = s.utm WHERE s.name = %L )'
                , 'specie_'||r.name, r.name);
     --If needed, replace CREATE TABLE above by CREATE VIEW
     --Add here for constrains, index, etc..
    END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Comment: It works smooth and fast, creating all the tables with no need to type each species' name.

Answer (score 6):

Simplest thing to do is to literally create a *View* for each `species`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW <species_x> AS (
  SELECT
      s.name,
      s.status,
      g.utm,
      g.geom::GEOMETRY(POLYGON, <SRID>)
  FROM
      species AS s
  JOIN
      grid AS g USING (utm)
  WHERE
      s.name = '<species_x>
);
```

---

**However:**

Instead of to automate creation, update and deletion of hundreds of relations, a function to return data for a given species would be more dynamic; here a naïve example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SpeciesStatusMap (
  species TEXT
) RETURNS TABLE AS (
  name   TEXT,
  status TEXT,
  utm    INT,
  geom   GEOMETRY(POLYGON, <SRID>)
) LANGUAGE SQL PARALLEL SAFE STRICT AS
  $$
    SELECT
      s.name,
      s.status,
      g.utm,
      g.geom::GEOMETRY(POLYGON, <SRID>)
    FROM
      species AS s
    JOIN
      grid AS g USING (utm)
    WHERE
      s.name = $1
    ;
  $$
;
```

and use it as:

```
SELECT *
FROM   SpeciesStatusMap('<species_x>')
;
```

*Note: replace all text in the query wrapped in `<>` with your specific values.*

The latter approach is by far more versatile and perfectly suitable for medium sized data-sets.

---

Note that you want to ensure you have an index in place on `grid.utm` and `species.name`!

Comment: The problem with this approach is that one must type each species' name. Having several hundreds of species, it takes sooooo much time. The loop proposed by @JB_D's answer makes the work automatically.

Comment: Sure, but you end up with having hundreds of Views to maintain. The function gives you the exact performance of a View, for whatever species you are looking for. Your choice. I don't mind if you like having Views better.

Comment: Now I understand. Very relevant. Thank you very much for explaining.